# Javascript, From 1 to 500, rather then 1 and 2

Tags: javascript

I have a problem. :)
I want my javascript code to go from 1 to 500. But now it just going 1 AND 2 that would mean that i would have to enter alot of data to get to 500. 
So i am looking for a sysmbol to set this code from-to.

Here is the code i am using, with this code everything in between 2 and 49 get the result Hm... 1 and 50 get the result 15 Tage. How can i change that:

```
if(conversion_inner==0 )
             con_dropdown_cnt.val('35 Tage');
        else if(conversion_inner==1 || conversion_inner==50 )
             con_dropdown_cnt.val('15 Tage');
        else if(conversion_inner==51 || conversion_inner==100 )
            con_dropdown_cnt.val('16 Tage');
        else if(conversion_inner==101 || conversion_inner==300 )
            con_dropdown_cnt.val('18 Tage');
        else if(conversion_inner==301 || conversion_inner==450 )
            con_dropdown_cnt.val('20 Tage');
        else if(conversion_inner==451 || conversion_inner==500 )
            con_dropdown_cnt.val('22 Tage');
        else
            con_dropdown_cnt.val('Hmmm...');
        cart_update();
```

Anyone?

Comment: Do you want something like: `else if(conversion_inner>=1 && conversion_inner<=50 )`

Comment: Also, remember to use curly braces `{` `}` for your control structures.  They are important.

Comment: Hi @DavinTryon, i did what you and @Oleh Leskiv told me, but now the 
`con_dropdown_cnt.val('ANY');` dies not update, it's always on 35 Tage.

Comment: @AnnaSimona if you always on `"35 Tage"` so your `conversion_inner==0` always

Comment: @DavinTryon, no there is a initial value 0 that displays `35 Tage`, if you enter a number from 1 to 15 then that number should change from `35 Tage` to `15 Tage`. (This is working but in my old code where i have `||`)

Comment: so how you get `conversion_inner`?

Comment: @Grudy 

`conversion_inner = $(this).val();
   conversion_inner = Number(conversion_inner);
   conversion_inner_cost = conversion_inner*conversion_cost;
   var con_dropdown_cnt =  $('input[name=etaDropDown]:text');
   $('input[name=innerpage_cost]:text').val(conversion_inner_cost);`

Comment: where you call code from OP?

Comment: @Davin Tryon, thank you for your help.
I had an error after that code...

Comment: @Gruday, thank you for your help.
I had an error after that code...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you need smthg like this

```
if(conversion_inner==0 ){
    con_dropdown_cnt.val('35 Tage');
} 
else if(conversion_inner>=1 && conversion_inner<=50 ){
     con_dropdown_cnt.val('15 Tage');
} 
else if(conversion_inner>=51 && conversion_inner<=100 ){
    con_dropdown_cnt.val('16 Tage');
} 
else if(conversion_inner>=101 && conversion_inner<=300 ){
    con_dropdown_cnt.val('18 Tage');
} 
else if(conversion_inner>=301 && conversion_inner<=450 ){
    con_dropdown_cnt.val('20 Tage');
} 
else if(conversion_inner>=451 && conversion_inner<=500 ){
    con_dropdown_cnt.val('22 Tage');
} 
else{
    con_dropdown_cnt.val('Hmmm...');
}
cart_update();
```

Comment: Hi @Oleh Leksiv, thank you. But now the `con_dropdown_cnt.val('ANY');` does not update it's always on 35 Tage, no mather what number i enter.

Comment: If i use this exact code that @Oleh Leskiv posted the `con_dropdown_cnt.val` is stuck at 35 Tage, no mather what number i enter.